# Modeling a sequence in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Does Alloy have the ability to model a sequence? I could do it manually (i.e create a `succeeds` relation, and list all the `one X` where it applies), but imagine there is a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Alloy have the ability to model a sequence?

Yes.

> I could do it manually (i.e create a succeeds relation, and list all the one X where it applies),

Yes, and in some cases that is the way you want to go.

> but imagine there is a more elegant approach.

As Colonel Thirty Two has already pointed out, `util/ordering` can be helpful, as can `util/seqrel` and `util/sequence`.

But in Alloy 4, the simplest route to sequences is the `seq` keyword documented [on the Alloy website](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/seq.html).  I believe it was introduced after the second edition of *Software abstractions* went to press; at least, there's no index entry there for `seq`.